# Convert multiple .wav to .caf

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making an iPhone app and I have a ton of `.wav` files I need to convert to `.caf`

I can use this for each file:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI8@22050 walking.wav walking.caf
```

But that would take ages, so I'm trying to convert all files with:

```
for i in *.wav; do afconvert -f -caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 $i ${i%.wav}.caf; done
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL failed ('typ?')
```

EDIT:The error will actually occur because of a typo in the for loop shown above. It should be `caff` not `-caff`. The correct code snippet would then be.

```
for i in *.wav; do afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 $i ${i%.wav}.caf; done
```

There may be other issues and the accepted answer is valid, just wanted to help out with making the question clear. /EDIT

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the script i have been using, slightly modified from another source, which kindly deserves all credit:

```
##
## Shell script to batch convert all files in a directory to caf sound format for iPhone
## Place this shell script a directory with sound files and run it: 'sh afconvert_wavtocaf.sh'
## Any comments to 'support@ezone.com'
##

for f in *.wav; do
if  [ "$f" != "afconvert_wavtocaf.sh" ]
then
 afconvert -f caff -d ima4 $f
 echo "$f converted"
fi
done
```

Save this in a file named 'afconvert_wavtocaf.sh'. See if that does the trick.

Comment: You can simply do `afconvert -f caff -d ima4 file.wav`

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `echo $i;` before `afconvert` in your script to get the name of sound file your command fails on. Then try to convert it manually, it will probably fail too.

I suspect one of your files is not an actual wav, but is in format not recognizable by `afconvert`.